# Duplicate an html tag with VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I am looking to clone this tag the number of times there is a day in the month:

```
<td class="day noclass" v-on:click="workedDay" :class="{ active: isActive }"></td>
```

I tried with that:

```
let tdCells;
  for ( let j = 1; j <= this.nbDaysInMonth; j++)
  {
    tdCells = document.createElement("td");
    tdCells.setAttribute("class", "dayOfMonth");
    tdCells.setAttribute(":class", "{ active: isActive }");
    tdCells.setAttribute("v-on:click", "workedDay");
    document.getElementsByClassName('cells')[0].appendChild(tdCells);
  }
```

but it creates html attribute but not usable with VueJs

Comment: What you're looking for is `v-for`. I suggest you read the basic vuejs introduction https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/.

Comment: This is not how VueJS works.You shouldn't touch DOM directly, everything should go over the model aka `data` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use v-for to loop through object

```
<tr v-for="day in nbDaysInMonth">
    <td class="day noclass" v-on:click="workedDay" :class="{ active: isActive }"></td>
</tr>
```